# How to typeset a filepath as plain text?

Tags: texmaker

I'm trying to typeset a manual with Texmaker for a computer program I've been working on, but I'm getting undefined control sequence errors when I try to insert a filepath in the format C:\Users\username. . .

There's probably an obvious solution, but it's been a long while since I used latex, and I can't find any answers online.

To make it clear, I'm trying to insert this filepath as plain text only, no fancy links, it's just text within  sentence.

Comment: Because `\Users` would be interpreted as command you have to either declare the `\ ` as string (e.g. `\string\Users`) or replace `\ ` by `\textbackslash` or use `\verb|C:\Users\username|` or `\url{C:\Users\username}` (needs package `url`).

Comment: I used \textbackslash and it's working fine, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`\verb+C:\Users\username...+`, where `+` is a character that does not appear in the string inside.
You can also put it inside 
`\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}`.

Comment: I tried verbatim but it formatted the text in an undesired fashion. I've used \textbackslash which someone here suggested and it is working fine